# how to enable CORS with Vert.x 2.x

Tags: angularjs, cors, vert.x

I am trying to make cross-domain requests with Angularjs 1.4.5.
But can't get success. I have configured $httpprovider

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept']= "application/json, text/plain, */*";
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8";
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8";
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authenticationFailedInterceptor');
    }])
```

But still con't get success. How to enable CORS support with Vert.x 2.x http server.

CORS is supported in Vert.x 3.x but Right now I can't upgrade Vert.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete example to enable cors:

We need to create two route matcher.

One helps to enable cors and other handle the requests.

Below is to enable cors. It Accept all request and add all the required headers needs to enable cors. After that we need to hand over request to the actual route matcher to handle request. We have that by the name secureRoutes.

```
RouteMatcher routeMatcher = new RouteMatcher();
        routeMatcher.options(".*",new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(final HttpServerRequest request) {
                request.response().putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                request.response().putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
                request.response().putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "accept, authorization, content-type, email");
                request.response().end();
            }
        })
        .all(".*",new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(final HttpServerRequest request) {
                request.response().putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                secureRoutes.getRouteMatcher().handle(request);
            }
        });
```

Another route matcher:

```
public class SecureRoutes {
private static final RouteMatcher routeMatcher = new RouteMatcher();
@Inject
protected Container container;
@Inject
private SigninController signinController;
@Inject
private SignupController signupController;
@Inject
private OauthController oauthController;
@Inject
ClientNetworkSignalController clientNetworkSignalController;

public void initRoutes() {
    // APP routes. they use User token for authentication


    routeMatcher.get("/", new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(final HttpServerRequest request) {
            request.response().putHeader("Cache-Control",
                    "public, max-age=86400");
            request.response().sendFile("web/public/index.html");
        }
    });


    routeMatcher.post("/signin", signinController.signin());
    routeMatcher.post("/signup", signupController.signup());
    routeMatcher.post("/oauth2/token", oauthController.token());
    routeMatcher.post("/oauth2/invalidate_token", oauthController.invalidateToken());

}

public RouteMatcher getRouteMatcher() {
    return routeMatcher;
}
```

}

Now finally add requestHandler to server:

```
server.requestHandler(routeMatcher).listen(port,
                host, new Handler<AsyncResult<HttpServer>>() {
                    public void handle(AsyncResult<HttpServer> asyncResult) {
                        if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
                            logger.info(s + ":  Started on " + host + ":"
                                    + port);
                        } else {
                            logger.info(s + ": Unable to start server.\n "
                                    + asyncResult.cause());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

You may have a question What is the use of http options type request handler. The answer is for that is very interesting. Javascript is a secured language that do not allow Cross origin Http request. So, to allow  cross origin request javascript send a options type request for each http request request and check weather CORS is supported or not. In such Javascript hits server two times one to check cors is supported or not and  one to fatch data.

Comment: I tried this approach. It is working fine for POST requests and not working for GET requests. Any suggestions on this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried with something like this on your responses?

```
vertx.createHttpServer()
  .requestHandler(function (req) {
    req.response()
      .putHeader("content-type", "text/plain")
      .putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
      .putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
      .putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
      .end("Hello from Vert.x!");
}).listen(8080);
```

for sure, you have to modify this to your needs... but the changes has to be done in the server and at least, you need these three headers.

Comment: Thanks for your time. In such case we have only one request handler. What if we need multiple request handlers?  Does we need to put these headers in every request handler?

Comment: As I don't know Vert very good (and it seems to be a great framework!) I don't know if you can set this kind of things in default headers. WebAPI and ServiceStack allows it.