# CORS issue in including headers to the response of Vertx application

Tags: java, cors, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, vert.x

I'm currently experiencing an issue with including the necessary CORS headers in my Vert.x application. Despite trying the solutions provided in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996253/cors-issue-in-vertx-application-not-working), I haven't been able to successfully add the headers to the response. When attempting to send a request from my frontend, I receive the following error message:

```
Acess to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/api' from origin 'http://localhost:4287' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The relevant code snippet from my HttpServerVerticle class is as follows:

```
> public class HttpServerVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) {
        ApiServiceApiHandler apiHandler = new ApiServiceApiHandler(new ApiServiceApiImpl());

        RouterBuilder.create(vertx, specFile)
                .map(builder -> {
                    builder.setOptions(
                            new RouterBuilderOptions()
                                    // For production use case, you need to enable this flag and provide the
                                    // proper security handler
                                    .setRequireSecurityHandlers(false));

                    vertx.eventBus().registerDefaultCodec(DBUserRequest.class, new LocalEventBusCodec<>(DBUserRequest.class));
                    vertx.eventBus().registerDefaultCodec(ArrayList.class, new LocalEventBusCodec<>(ArrayList.class));

                    apiHandler.mount(builder);

                  Router router = builder.createRouter();

                    router.route().handler(CorsHandler.create("http://localhost:4287")
                            .allowedMethod(io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod.GET)
                            .allowedMethod(io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod.POST)
                            .allowedMethod(io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
                            .allowCredentials(true)
                            .allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Method")
                            .allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
                            .allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials")
                            .allowedHeader("Content-Type"));

              router.errorHandler(400, new ExceptionHandler());
              router.errorHandler(405, new ExceptionHandler());
              router.errorHandler(404, new ExceptionHandler());



                    return router;

                })
               .compose(router->vertx.createHttpServer(options).requestHandler(router).listen(Vertx.currentContext().config().getInteger(ConfigConstants.PROPERTY_SERVICE_HTTP_PORT));
.onSuccess(server -> logger.info("Http verticle deploy successful"))
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve the CORS issue mentioned above.

I have already tried the solution mentioned in this link - [CORS issue in vertx Application not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996253/cors-issue-in-vertx-application-not-working)

Also I tried by changing the origin to ".*." but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `Router` with the `RouterBuidler` for OpenAPI, there are routes already defined.

So if you define a route for the `CorsHandler`, it will be installed as the last route definition.

For that case, you could add the `CorsHandler` route first, then mount the `Router` for OpenAPI as a sub-router:

```java
// Create the top-level router
Router router = Router.router(vertx);

// Define a route for the CorsHandler immediately
router.route().handler(CorsHandler.create("http://localhost:4287")
                            .allowedMethod(io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod.GET)
                            .allowedMethod(io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod.POST)
                            .allowedMethod(io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
                            .allowCredentials(true)
                            .allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Method")
                            .allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
                            .allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials")
                            .allowedHeader("Content-Type"));

// Define a subrouter for routes generated from OpenAPI spec
router.route().subRouter(builder.createRouter());
```